# combining values for a large number of overlapping intervals of dictionary keys

Tags: python, data-structures, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionaries that has items like this

```
all={
    1:{ ('a',123,145):20, ('a',155,170):12, ('b',234,345): 34},
    2:{ ('a',121,135):10, ('a',155,175):28, ('b',230,345): 16},
    3:{ ('a',130,140):20, ('a',150,170):10, ('b',234,345): 30}, 
    ...
    n: {...}
}
```

edit: The dictionary names are arbitrarily given by me according to the file names the initial data is read from, I can use any value I want to name these dictionaries.
I would like to get the sum of these values for each overlapping region. The output showing how the overlaps should be like is this

```
 { ('a',121,122):10, ('a',123,130):30, ('a',131,135):50, 
   ('a',136,140):40,('a',141,145):20, ...}
```

edit: Each dictionary has non-overlapping intervals so there never is ('a',2,10) and ('a',3,12) in a given dictionary but the intervals overlap between dictionaries as the start and end positions are not the same (i.e keys are not the same between dictionaries).

I don't have to use the dictionary data structure and since I have created this dictionary in the first place, if this is more easy to do with lists, sets etc I can get the data in one of those structures, I can work with another solution based on a different data structure as well.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: define "unique overlapping region"

Comment: How was the dict generated? I'm mostly curious what the significance of the 1, 2, 3, ... n, are.

Comment: If the keys to your `all` dict are sequential numbers, it probably makes more sense to use a list for that. But can you be a bit clearer about "the sum of these values for each unique overlapping region". I'm not entirely sure how you get to your output...

Comment: If I understand your method correctly (which I may not, as you're not explaining what you're doing) it should be ('a',130,135):50 instead of ('a',130,135):40.

Comment: @canavanin: thanks for finding this out. You are right. I have corrected the question.

Comment: @Thomas, @THC4k. Are my edits clear enough? Please let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: @martineau you re-introduced the error in biomed's sample output.

Comment: @biomed: I still don't get it. I guess `('a',121,123):10` comes from `('a',123,145):20, ('a',121,135):10` but I don't see how?

Comment: @THC4k No, ('a',123,145):20 is not involved there, as it does not contain 121.

Comment: @biomed: If your data structure made some sense it would be much clearer .. ie would something like `{'a' : [((123,145), 20), ((121,135),10)], 'b' : ... }` make more sense (separating the 'a' from 'b's) ?

Comment: @canavanin: But they do overlap ... ? These are intervals, right? Or just two dots each and finding the intervals is the problem? Where do the values belong to then?

Comment: @THC4k As how I understand it you don't necessarily take the intervals that are given in the datastructure; the values contained in them just provide the boundaries of the intervals you're actually looking for. By 'overlap' COMPLETE and not partial overlap is meant (at least that is my interpretation of the sample output). Hhm, that explanation of mine sounds a bit clumsy, sorry :/

Comment: These are chromosomal positions.  A,b,c etc were given to make it easy to understand instead of chr1,chr2 etc. And @THC4k I can't change the data to the format you suggested due to reasons related to underlying biological relationships.

Comment: @THC4k Ok, now the sample output has been changed once again... argh!

Comment: @biomed: if you have the data in the format currently shown, it can be reformatted into something like what THC4k is suggesting.

Comment: @biomed Could you please explain what exactly you're trying to do, and what the numbers in the chromosomes represent - base pair intervals and mutation counts, for example (just a random guess...); that would make the question a bit easier to deal with (for me at least).

Comment: @bioment: What i meant was that you can do all the 'a' without looking at any of the 'b's ? Please write a few examples of items you can combine and of items you can't combine, ie `{('a',1,10) : 10} + {('a',2,9) : 10} = {('a',1,10) : 20}` ? You can still give the sample input later, but not everyone does bioinformatics ;-p

Comment: @canavanin the data is about coverage for a given genetic interval and each file(dictionary is about a different patient) I am trying to get the average coverage value for each genomic interval.  Hope it is not too much biology.

Comment: @biomed What is meant by 'coverage' in this context? I know it's getting off-topic now, sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now i think i get it: Basically you have a bunch of overlapping intervals, represented by bars at a certain position with a given thickness. You would draw these bars below each other and see how thick they are together at any given point.

I think it's easiest/fastest to abuse the fact that you have integer positions to do this:

```
all={
    1:{ ('a',123,145):20, ('a',155,170):12, ('b',234,345): 34},
    2:{ ('a',121,135):10, ('a',155,175):28, ('b',230,345): 16},
    3:{ ('a',130,140):20, ('a',150,170):10, ('b',234,345): 30}
}

from collections import defaultdict
summer = defaultdict(int)
mini, maxi = 0,0
for d in all.values():
    for (name, start, stop), value in d.iteritems(): 
        # im completely ignoring the `name` here, not sure if that's what you want
        # else just separate the data before doing this ...
        if mini == 0:
            mini = start
        mini, maxi = min(mini, start), max(maxi, stop)
        for i in range(start, stop+1):
            summer[i]+=value

# now we have the values at each point, very redundant but very fast so  far
print summer

# now we can find the intervals:
def get_intervals(points, start, stop):
    cstart = start
    for i in range(start, stop+1):
        if points[cstart] != points[i]: # did the value change ?
            yield cstart, i-1, points[cstart]
            cstart = i

    if cstart != i:
        yield cstart, i, points[cstart]


print list(get_intervals(summer, mini, maxi))
```

When using only the 'a' items it give:

```
[(121, 122, 10), (123, 129, 30), (130, 135, 50), (136, 140, 40), (141, 145, 20), (146, 149, 0), (150, 154, 10), (155, 170, 50), (171, 175, 28)]
```

### Edit: It just hit me how to do this really simple:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from heapq import heappush, heappop

class Summer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # its a priority queue, kind of like a sorted list
        self.hq = []

    def additem(self, start, stop, value):
        # at `start` add it as a positive value
        heappush(self.hq, (start, value))
        # at `stop` subtract that value again
        heappush(self.hq, (stop, -value))

    def intervals(self):
        hq = self.hq
        start, val = heappop(hq)
        while hq:
            point, value = heappop(hq)
            yield start, point, val
            # just maintain the current value and where the interval started
            val += value
            start = point
        assert val == 0

summers = defaultdict(Summer)
for d in all.values():
    for (name, start, stop), value in d.iteritems():
        summers[name].additem(start, stop, value)

for name,s in summers.iteritems():
    print name, list(s.intervals())
```

Comment: You have omitted the a and b's from the answer but it still will let me implement this. If the positions of a's and b's overlap then it would have a problem but as I said it is good enough. I hope it is efficient enough for >100 dictionaries with >100.000 data points. I hope I 'll let you know the results. Thanks

Comment: @biomed: There are plenty of optimizations left, ie maybe you know the mini, maxi positions before, then you could replace the dict with a numpy.array of a fixed size and use indices .. that would save a lot of memory. Speaking of numpy, I wouldn't be surprised to find something there that does this. Maybe my description is a bit more understandable to others too :P

Comment: Yes, I would definitely look at using a numpy array to do the counting if the range from mini to maxi is densely covered. It will be faster (hash look-up versus index) in addition to saving memory.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, if these are chromosomes, lets start by mapping them out separately:

```
{"Chr1": {(121,122):10, (123,130):30, ...},
"Chr2": {(230,233):16, ...},
...
}
```

The numbers you're adding up are, I take it, some sort of scores--expression scores or whatever.

If the range of positions (these 121, 130 numbers definining the intervals) is small enough--anything up to several thousand--then you'd probably save yourself a headache by storing a summed score for each position, and simply adding the score for an interval to every position within that interval.

If they're something like individual base positions, and there are millions of possible positions, you'll need to stick with intervals. So for each one, you'll need to check the relevant chromosome for intervals it overlaps, then remove those, and break them down into as many smaller intervals as you need to store all the different summed scores.

Here's a rough framework, but it's not complete:

```
for (start, end), score in intervals_to_add.items():
    overlapping = {}
    for (start1, end1), score1 in current_chromosome.items():
        if start1 <= start <= end1 or start1 <= end <= end1:
            overlapping[(start1, end1)] = score1
    for interval in overlapping:
        current_chromosome.pop(interval)
    # Process overlapping into smaller intervals, adding in the current interval
    current_chromosome.update(new_intervals)
```